# 'Up' shortcut in Files not working anymore

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts

Since Juno i can't use the "up" command. In loki with the backspace key i was able to use it. There is some way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shortcut has been removed from Files and has started being removed from major browsers too as it leads to unpredictable behavior. The backspace key is intended to delete the character before the cursor, not do anything else.

There is an alternative shortcut in [files](/questions/tagged/files) which is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

Comment: There's also <ALT> + <UP ARROW>